# How can multiple tabs be created from a range using Google Apps Script in a Google Sheet?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need to create a custom function to create multiple tabs in a Google Sheet based on the values in column A.  How do I do this?

This is for tracking the data on particular e-commerce products.  The name of them are in the first column of the first tab.  Each entry in column A needs to have a tab labeled as the same name.

I don't know how to do this.

The output should be new tabs created labeled by each cell in column A.

Comment: take array of column a, and then from the array iterate the item, you check the existing tab with item as its name, if not exist, you create new tab, of course with item as it's name

Answer (score 0):

Copy and paste this code in the script editor.

```
function createSheet(sheetIndex, value){
  // Check if cell is empty after editing
  if (value.oldValue){
    value = 'Sheet' + (sheets.length - sheetIndex);
  }

  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();

  // If sheet already exits just change the sheet name
  if (sheets[sheetIndex]) {
    sheets[sheets.length - sheetIndex].setName(value)
  } else {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().insertSheet(value);
  }
}

function onEdit(e) {
  var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();

  // Check if the sheet being edited is the first sheet and first column (A)
  if (sheet.getSheetId() == sheets[0].getSheetId() && sheet.getActiveCell().getColumn() == 1) {
    createSheet(e.range.getRowIndex(), e.value)
  }

}
```

You can extend the code to support deletion; it's a bit tricky though because there is no onDelete event. You can compare the sheets array with the values in the column to determine which sheet delete.

Answer (score 0):

**Creating Multiple Sheets with Templates and Position**

1. Open a new Spreadsheet and go to script editor
2. Load the Code and Save it
3. Create the sheet named "Sheet Data"
4. Create the three templates
5. Run createTrigger()
6. Close the Spreadsheet
7. Open the Spreadsheet give it some time and it will create all of the sheets without bothering the templates or the Sheet Data sheet.
   The Code:

```
    function onOpen() {
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu("My Menu")
      .addItem('Create onOpen Trigger', 'createTrigger')
      .addToUi();
    }
    //This is where the sheets get created  
    function startUp() {
      var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
      var templateA=["A","B","C"];
      templateA.forEach(function(name){ss.getSheetByName(name).hideSheet();});
      var sh=ss.getSheetByName("Sheet Data");
      var shts=ss.getSheets();
      var shtnames=shts.map(function(sh){if(!sh.isSheetHidden()){return sh.getName();}}).filter(function(e){return e});
      var hdnshts=shts.map(function(sh){if(sh.isSheetHidden()){return sh.getName();}}).filter(function(e){return e});
      var rg=sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow()-1,sh.getLastColumn());
      var vA=rg.getValues();
      vA.sort(function(a,b){return a[2]-b[2];});
      vA.forEach(function(r){
        if(shtnames.indexOf(r[0])==-1 && r[0]!=sh.getName()) {
          ss.insertSheet(r[0], r[2], {template:ss.getSheetByName(r[1])});
        }
        shts=ss.getSheets();
        shtnames=shts.map(function(sh){if(!sh.isSheetHidden()){return sh.getName();}}).filter(function(e){return e});
      });
      var end="is near";
    }

    function isTrigger(funcName){
      var r=false;
      if(funcName){
        var allTriggers=ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
        for(var i=0;i<allTriggers.length;i++){
          if(funcName==allTriggers[i].getHandlerFunction()){
            r=true;
            break;
          }
        }
      }
      return r;
    }

    //Installable onOpen trigger
    //run this function first
    function createTrigger() {
      var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
      if(!isTrigger('startUp')) {//This keeps you from creating unnecessary triggers
        ScriptApp.newTrigger('startUp').forSpreadsheet(ss).onOpen().create()
      }
    }

    //This is useful for testing
    function deleteSheets() {
      var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
      var sh=ss.getSheetByName("Sheet Data");
      var rg=sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow()-1,sh.getLastColumn());
      var vA=rg.getValues();
      vA.forEach(function(r){
        ss.deleteSheet(ss.getSheetByName(r[0]));
      });
    }
```

The Creation Sheet:

[image]

Three Templates:
I just made these templates up as simple examples to assist in the creation of your sheets.  I find that non programmers really excel at this process making extremely fancy spreadsheets.  For me, I keep them simple.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I tried using this gif to show how the files are create with the spreadsheet opens up the first time.  It won't create additional sheets of the same name.  But if you add additional names it will create them.  It's not capable of deleting sheet names that have been removed, so there's something you can do for yourself.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much - This is beyond helpful!

Answer (score 0):

This function below creates a new sheet every time a cell from column A in your original sheet is edited, only if another sheet with this name does not exist already. To accomplish that, and [onEdit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite) trigger is used, as well as the corresponding [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit):

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var firstSheetName = "Sheet1"; // Name of your original sheet, change accordingly
  var range = e.range; // Edited cell
  var ss = e.source; // Edited spreadsheet
  var sheetName = range.getSheet().getName(); // Name of edited sheet
  var value = range.getValue(); // Value of the edited cell
  // Checks whether edited sheet is the original one, and edited column is A:
  if(sheetName == firstSheetName && range.getColumn() == 1) {
    // Checks whether a sheet with this name exists:
    var sheetExists = ss.getSheets().some(function(sheet) {
      return sheet.getName() == value;
    });
    // Create new sheet only if a sheet with this name it doesn't exist:
    if(!sheetExists) { 
      ss.insertSheet(value);
      range.activate(); // Go back to original edited cell
    }
  }
}
```

- See the comments in the shared script to understand what the code is doing, step by step.
- In this example, the original sheet is called "Sheet1". Change it accordingly if that's not your case.

I hope this is of any help.